# JPA Entity mapping SQL Function result to transient field

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

Instead of calling SQL function "manually" for every entity, is there any way to map its result to an entity transient field's ?

```
@XXXX(call function with param ?)
private int calculatedValue;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use Hibernate's `@Formula` annotation:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Formula.html

https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-calculate-entity-attributes-formula/